# tc = int(input()) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12 21 34 45 21'

Tags: python, valueerror

I want the user to be able to enter all the numbers on a single line. How can I do this?

```py
class Solution:
    def print2largest(self,arr, n):
        largest = arr[0]
        for i in range(n):
            if largest < arr[i]:
                largest = arr[i]
        second_largest = arr[0]
        for j in range(n):
            if second_largest < arr[j]:
                if arr[j] != largest:
                    second_largest = arr[j]
                    
N=int(input("Enter total number"))
arr = []
for i in range(N):
    num = int(input("enter numbers :"))
    arr.append(num)
    
obj = Solution()
obj.print2largest(arr,N)
```

I tried the above code, but it doesn’t work. I get a ValueError.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press enter after every number that you give.

Answer (score 0):

input() reads a line and returns a string back. If you want to read numbers in a line, try this.

```
N = int(input("Enter total number"))
s = input("enter numbers :").split() #Get the numbers together and then separate them
arr = [int(x) for x in s] #Add each of the entered numbers to a list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for multiple values on a single input (string). You could make the code more flexible by allowing for either multiple or single inputs.

For example:

```
class Solution:
    # n is not needed
    def print2largest(self, arr, n):
        return sorted(arr)[-2:]

N = int(input('Enter total number: '))

arr = []

while len(arr) < N:
    value = input('Enter number(s): ')
    arr += [int(n) for n in value.split()]

if len(arr) > N:
    print('Too many values')
else:
    print(Solution().print2largest(arr, N))
```

**Console:**

```
Enter total number: 5
Enter number(s): 1
Enter number(s): 9
Enter number(s): 3 4 5
[5, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood of your question, you want to enter all the numbers together at the same time. To do that, you can use the following code:

```
arr = [] #Create an empty list
total_num = ("Enter total number of values:")
nums = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces:") #Get numbers from the user
nums = nums.split() #Separate the numbers entered by the user
if len(nums) <= total_num:
    for number in nums:
        arr.append(int(number)) #Add each number to the list

else:
    print("Number of values more than maximum limit")
```

Comment: num_list will be a list of strings rather than integers which seems to be the requirement